# Convert JSON Array in CSV with row name?

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv, export-to-excel

I don't know how to convert this JSON array into a CSV.

```
[relatedProducts] => Array
(
    [0] => 111001
    [1] => 111002
    [2] => 111007
    [3] => 111021
    [4] => 111022
    [5] => 111024
    [6] => 111027
    [7] => 111121
    [8] => 111122
    [9] => 111127
    [10] => 111128
    [11] => 111141
    [12] => 111142
    [13] => 111144
    [14] => 111147
)
```

I want `relatedProducts` to be the row name and in the field below of `relatedProducts` there should be "111001,111002,111007....."

```
relatedProducts
111001,111002,111007
```

What I have tried is something like this:

```
foreach($array as $obj)
{ 
    $related = $obj->relatedProducts;
};
if (empty($firstLineKeys))
{
    $firstLineKeys = array_keys($relatedProducts); 
    fputcsv($f, $firstLineKeys, ';');
    $firstLineKeys = array_flip($firstLineKeys);
}
fputcsv($f, $relatedProducts, ';');
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you ask, with the limited data and context provided:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
  print("$k\n".implode(',', $v)."\n");
}
```

Outputs

> relatedProducts
>   111001,111002,111007,111021,111022,111024,111027,111121,111122,111127,111128,111141,111142,111144,111147